# How to Pass POJO over JMS Queue in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

I am relatively new to Jboss Fuse & Apache Camel. I poll a directory for specific XML files (using file filter) and extract info from XML content and save it in POJO, which then needs to be sent over JMS Queue (databaseQueue) along with the XML file to a route where I need to extract the params from POJO and insert in Database. But I am unable to pass the POJO over JMS queue to be able to retrieve in another route. I can't set the POJO in body as the original payload will be lost. Please help. Below is the sample route.

```
<route id="fileRoute">
        <from uri="file:{{PFlowIn_AEROW}}?delay={{PFlowScanDelay}}&amp;filter=#fileFilter&amp;delete=true"/>                 
        <process ref="saveFlowParamsInPOJO"/>
        <recipientList>
            <simple>activemq:queue:databaseQueue, activemq:queue:messageArchiveQueue, activemq:queue:XmlValidationQueue</simple>
        </recipientList>
    </route>
```

Comment: show your code for saveFlowParamsInPOJO

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you can only set one Object in message body, however you have two options.

- Maybe you can deal with an object that contains the XML and your POJO.
- Another option is to try to add the POJO to the message headers. Try to add it in your Processor step and the retrieve it from the other side.

  ```
  exchange.getIn().setHeader("myPOJO", POJOvalue);
  ```

**Edit:**

As @BeenaRautela indicates, the second option proposed is not valid because headers only accepts non-object data type.

Another options are:

- Send the POJO in the message body and try to send the XML as String in a header.
- Store the POJO params in a Map and set it in a header.

Comment: I tried the second option. When I set the pojo in message headers , it only accepts non-object data type  and when I try to retrieve back as POJO, it throws ClassCastException like NoType Converter available to convert from string to the required POJO type.

Comment: @BeenaRautela Oh I'm sorry. It is feasible to send the POJO params as headers values? If the POJO params are primitives values it can be an option.

Comment: @BeenaRautela Related to this question I found this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469762/apache-camel-can-message-have-multiple-objects-in-body-with-different-classes?rq=1

Comment: Yes, the Pojo params are primitive data types. However they are 10-12 parameters as of now and may change later to 20 or something. So need a better solution to manage them.

Comment: Using simple you can set a Map in headers with all your POJO params. More info: http://camel.apache.org/simple.html

Comment: Maybe another option is to set the POJO in the body message and the XML as String in a header.

Answer (score 0):

> Convert your POJO into data-interchange format (e.g. json) and save into header

1. Convert POJO to json string
2. Save json string into message header
3. Convert json string to POJO or map

---

You could import json library which are available in [apache camel json component](http://camel.apache.org/json.html) and then perform marshal/unmarshal.

If you wish to convert your POJO within your bean, you may also try Jackson ObjectMapper class to do conversion.

```java
// Convert from POJO to json String
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String pojoAsString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(yourPojo);

// Convert from json String to POJO
YourPojo yourPojo = objectMapper.readValue(pojoAsString , YourPojo.class);

// convert from json String to map
Map<String, Object> map = objectMapper.readValue(pojoAsString , new TypeReference<Map<String,Object>>(){});
```

[Source](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial) of above ObjectMapper examples